# Parse.com Push Object/Message from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, api, excel, parse-platform

I am trying to write a VBA script to push messages from Excel to my decives using the Parse.com framework. So far I succeeded in sending push data messages from the Parse.com website to multiple devices so that part should be good.

Problem is getting VBA to send a Push or even data to Parse.com in general.
At the moment I'm just trying to get the connection to work and push some data in to my TestObject Class. I am using the following code and authentication seems to go how it's supposed to be now! The PUT object gives an error: invalid json

```
Sub Parse()
TargetURL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject"
Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") '
HTTPReq.Open "POST", TargetURL, False
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxxxxx"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "xxxxxx"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
HTTPReq.send ("{foo:bar}")
MsgBox (HTTPReq.ResponseText)
End Sub
```

New Error:

Invalid Json

Comment: What doesn't work? Also the line `HTTPReq.send ("test[status]="foo":"bar")`. Shouldn't it be `HTTPReq.send ("test[status]=""foo"":""bar")`

Comment: @SiddharthRout the specific error message I get when testing the OP's code is, "A connection with the server could not be established", which makes me think authentication, especially given the instructions from the docs to include authentication key as part of the HTTP headers.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the update. The quotes did help me with one error but my problem is not yet solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up authentication? From the [Parse.com REST API reference](https://parse.com/docs/rest):

**Request Format**

For `POST` and `PUT` requests, the request body must be JSON, with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`.

Authentication is done via HTTP headers. The `X-Parse-Application-Id` header identifies which application you are accessing, and the `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` header authenticates the endpoint. In the examples that follow, the keys for your app are included in the command. You can use the drop-down to construct example code for other apps.

You may also authenticate your REST API requests using basic HTTP authentication. For example, to retrieve an object you could set the URL using your Parse credentials in the following format:

> https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm

For Javascript usage, the Parse Cloud supports cross-origin resource sharing, so that you can use these headers in conjunction with `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I updated my code in several ways with the authentication url specified above and another one I found at parse.com but it still isn't working. Above is my updated code. Could you be so kind as to change the bad parts?

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTPReq.send ("{""foo"":""bar""}")
```

Posting will be successful.